# How can I create a timeline of multiple subjects without using dates in R?

Tags: r, visualization, timeline

I have a dataset of subjects that I want to compare based on Days After Treatment rather than the actual dates of their treatments and follow ups.

My thought process is that it would be way easier to visualize if all the subjects would start at the same point and end at the same point rather than be spread across multiple years due to subjects starting at different times.

Is there a way to do this in R? I've looked at vistime, which looks promising except that start/end are supposed to be dates.

Here's an example of what my data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(Patient = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 Response = c("PR", "CR", "CR", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PR", "PR", "CR"),
                 Start = rep(c("Day 30", "Day 90", "Day 180")),
                 End = rep(c("Day 90", "Day 180", "Day 270")))
```

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGSMG.png)

Comment: Without a reproducible example of some data to work with it's difficult for us to give you concrete advice, but how about ```as.numeric(diff.Date(your data here))```.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Sorry, I'm new to this. I've added an example of my data.

Comment: There's definitely a way to do that in R. Look into the `lubridate` package, it's got really good tools for handling dates & converting them into counts of time periods (days, months, years, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

So from the example you posted your data isn't actually numeric or date, it's text.

```
df <- data.frame(Patient = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 Response = c("PR", "CR", "CR", "SD", "SD", "PD", "PR", "PR", "CR"),
                 Start = rep(c("Day 30", "Day 90", "Day 180")),
                 End = rep(c("Day 90", "Day 180", "Day 270")))

  Patient Response   Start     End
1       1       PR  Day 30  Day 90
2       1       CR  Day 90 Day 180
3       1       CR Day 180 Day 270
4       2       SD  Day 30  Day 90
5       2       SD  Day 90 Day 180
6       2       PD Day 180 Day 270
7       3       PR  Day 30  Day 90
8       3       PR  Day 90 Day 180
9       3       CR Day 180 Day 270
```

To work with text there are a bunch of options, including `tidyverse` below (there's also `base`, plus others).

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Start = as.numeric(str_extract(Start, "[:digit:]+")),
         End = as.numeric(str_extract(End, "[:digit:]+")),
         Difference = End - Start,
         )
```

What I've done is extracted the numeric portion of your start and end dates and then subtracted them.  That's what you're looking for right?

```
  Patient Response Start End Difference
1       1       PR    30  90         60
2       1       CR    90 180         90
3       1       CR   180 270         90
4       2       SD    30  90         60
5       2       SD    90 180         90
6       2       PD   180 270         90
7       3       PR    30  90         60
8       3       PR    90 180         90
9       3       CR   180 270         90
```